# adding more Values in tow Textinput Dynamic Arrays and getting the Sum in Label in the same screen,

Tags: python, arrays, list, dynamic, kivy

I am still a beginner in Kivy and have this **Issue** !
the User has to write different values in the first text input **"First Textinput Values Box"** and dot **"." between each value**, e.g. 12.32.3
if He press **"Enter"**, he get the possibility to create a new box, **"Second Textinput values box"**
and then he can continue to write the values in the 2nd box,**and dot"." between each value** e.g. two values 1.2
then He can press **Button "Result"**, He get the sum in the same Screen in 3 different **labels**.
The Label are : **first value** from the first box "12" plus **first value** from the second box "1"
**second value** from the first box "32" plus **second value** from the second box "2"
**third value** from the first box "3" plus **third value** from the second box "0"
can you please help me how can i make this **Dynamic Array in the Box ?** 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you'r asking for exactly. Do you want something like this?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout




Builder.load_string('''
<BestWindow>:
    inpt_one: inpt_one
    inpt_two: inpt_two
    result_layout: result_layout
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: inpt_one
        TextInput:
            id: inpt_two
        Button:
            text: "Add them up!"
            on_press: root.calculate()
        BoxLayout:
            id: result_layout
            orientation: "horizontal"

''')

class BestWindow(BoxLayout):
    my_result = StringProperty("")
    inpt_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    result_layout = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BestWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def calculate(self):
        self.result_layout.clear_widgets()
        nums_one = self.inpt_one.text.strip().split(".")
        nums_two = self.inpt_two.text.strip().split(".")
        if(len(nums_one) < len(nums_two)):
            for _ in range(len(nums_two)-len(nums_one)):
                nums_one.append(0)
        elif(len(nums_two) < len(nums_one)):
            for _ in range(len(nums_one)-len(nums_two)):
                nums_two.append(0)
        result = [int(x) + int(y) for x,y in zip(nums_one, nums_two)]

        for res in result:
            self.result_layout.add_widget(Label(text=str(res)))
        self.inpt_one.text = ''
        self.inpt_two.text = ''


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BestWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Hallo Australo , Thanks for your answer ... 
thanks for your answer .. yes something like that, but I need that at the beginning there is only unique text input .. then if you press "Enter" in keyboard you can get the second text input array, and input the Values , then if you press "space" in keyboard, you gets the result , how can i do it without Button or the second Textinput ? 
Danke im voraous